# Missing files in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'm missing the following files when I try to make a program i have downloaded using cygwin.  Does anyone know a patch or library I could download from the cygwin setup interface?

```
../ports/linux/net.h:78:23: net/route.h: No such file or directory
../ports/linux/net.h:80:24: net/if_arp.h: No such file or directory
../ports/linux/net.h:87:29: linux/if_packet.h: No such file or directory
../ports/linux/net.h:88:29: linux/if_arcnet.h: No such file or directory
../ports/linux/net.h:89:28: linux/if_ether.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Since this question has so few views, I'm going to vote to close it as "belongs on [superuser](http://www.superuser.com)"

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer by searching for any of these file names at the [Cygwin package search page](http://cygwin.com/packages/).

What you'll find is that they're not there.  They're not currently supported in Cygwin.